# c# How to show specific variables from a list?

Tags: c#, class, methods

So I'm working on a small program, that simulates a Tennis Tournament. 
I have a list of players(separate file) that I open up and place in a list, which I do in a Class. It is then shown like my ToString method in my Player Class:

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Name: {0} {1} {2}, Birthday: {3}, Age: {4}, From: {5} / {6}",
            first_name,
            middle_name,
            last_name,
            birthday.ToShortDateString(),
            Age,
            nationality_long,
            nationality_short);
    }
```

I need to simulate the Tennis game itself, but I want it to give me the Names of the players only (first_name, middle_name, last_name) and set it up as such:

```
Console.Clear();

        var player1 = participants.ElementAt(0);
        var player2 = participants.ElementAt(1);
        Console.WriteLine("Match 1: {0} vs. {1}", player1, player2);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

so it is shown as, for example: John Touchwich Smith vs. Sarah Catrine Nielsen.

Is there a way I can tell the program, to give the specific variables(first_name, middle_name, last_name) from the different elements in the list of participants, set them up and place them in a variable like above?

Or do I have to create similar classes, that opens the file, place the name information in a ToSting Method, place that information into a list, then take from that list? It seems it can be done much easier, then making more, almost identical classes.

Comment: How you do it is pretty much personal opinion.. what you need to come here with is I did it, but its not doing what i expected..

Comment: How is `participants` declared? I suppose every instance in the list has those variables, doesn´t it?

Comment: It would help greatly if we could see a representation of the player class. Do you have properties for accessing those variables, (public, private, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a class that represents a `Participant`. Within that class you have all those properties which you want to print. This class also know how to print itself - for which you can use your existing `ToString`-method:

```
class Player
{
    public string First_name { get; set; }
    public string middle_name { get; set; }
    public string Last_name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Nationality_long { get; set; }
    public string Nationality_short { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Name: {0} {1} {2}, Birthday: {3}, Age: {4}, From: {5} / {6}",
            first_name,
            middle_name,
            last_name,
            birthday.ToShortDateString(),
            Age,
            nationality_long,
            nationality_short);
    }
}
```

Now you can create instances of that class, e.g:

```
var p1 = new Player { Name = "John", MiddleName = "Touchwich", LastName = "Smith", ... other properties };
var p2 = new Player { ... }
```

Put those players into your list of participants:

```
participants.Add(p1);
participants.Add(p2);
```

Now finally extract the name of an element in that list, e.g. so:

```
var myPerson = participants.Single(x => x.Name == "John" && 
    x.MiddleName = "Touchwich" &&
    x.LastName = "Smith");
Console.WriteLine(myPerson)
```

The call to `WriteLine` will now implicitely call your `ToString``.

Comment: I experimented around with creating a participant class, and now it shows the way I intended. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If your `participants` variable is a `IEnumerable<Player>` then you can use a LINQ `Where()` method to filter out and get you the specific player like below (filter condition could be on any field you like. Possibly with a unique Id field)

```
var player = participants.Where(p => p.first_name == "John").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I think OP deson´t need the player whos name is `John`, but just the pre- middle- and last-name of a given player - if this class even exists what I doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be making some assumptions here since you don't have a copy of the Player class posted. I'll try to cover all the possibilities below. I'll update the answer if you do with concise specific answers.

Since you are enumerating using the ElementAt() you may be better off using a for loop over the data. With a List you could do this, given a property rather than ElementAt(). Also you can use .ToList() to cast the IEnumerable to a List (hard to know without the class).

```
participants[i].Firstname;
```

To select specific properties, such as all the first names via Select.

```
var specificThings = participants[i].Select(x => new { Firstname = x.Firstname, LastName = x.LastName });

var outputText = participants[i].Select(x => string.Format("Something {0} Something {1} Darkside", x.Firstname, x.Lastname).FirstOrDefault();
```

Which will give you a formatted string based on the properties.

The answer also depends on whether you are using IEnumerable or IEnumerable. If you are using ElementAt and it's not working try using `participants.Cast<Player>().ElementAt`.